# Returning function result inside class, how it works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

```
if not node:
    return node
```

What does this code mean?

```
if not node.leftchild:
    print('removing the node with single rightchild')
    tempnode = node.rightchild
    del node
    return tempnode
```

In removing items in Binary search tree when having one child, if a node is deleted, child need to be connected to other node. However, I don't understand how it works because there is no declaration pointing to the other node. How does "tempnode" work after return? I mean there is no uses after return but I see if i return None or other value instead of tempnode, removing is not working

Here is the full program.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.leftchild = None
        self.rightchild = None


class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if not self.root:
            self.root = Node(data)

        else:
            self.insert_node(data,self.root)

    def insert_node(self,data, node):

        if data < node.data:
            if node.leftchild:
                self.insert_node(data, node.leftchild)
            else:
                node.leftchild = Node(data)
        else:
            if node.rightchild:
                self.insert_node(data, node.rightchild)
            else:
                node.rightchild = Node(data)

    def remove(self, data):
        if self.root:
            self.root = self.remove_node(data, self.root)

    def remove_node(self, data, node):
        if not node:
            return node

        if data < node.data:
            node.leftchild = self.remove_node(data, node.leftchild)

        elif data > node.data:
            node.rightchild = self.remove_node(data, node.rightchild)

        else:

            if not node.leftchild and not node.rightchild:
                print('removing leaf node')
                del node
                return None

            if not node.leftchild:
                print('removing the node with single rightchild')
                tempnode = node.rightchild
                del node
                return tempnode

            elif not node.rightchild:
                print('removing the node with single lefttchild')
                tempnode = node.leftchild
                del node

                return tempnode

            print('removing the node with two childs')
            tempnode = self.get_predessor(node.leftchild)
            node.data = tempnode.data
            node.leftchild = self.remove_node(tempnode.data, node.leftchild)


        return node

    def get_predessor(self, node):

        if node.rightchild:
            return self.get_predessor(node.rightchild)

        return node




    def get_min_value(self):
        if self.root:
            return self.get_min(self.root)

    def get_min(self, node):
        if node.leftchild:
            return self.get_min(node.leftchild)

        return node.data

    def get_max_value(self):
        if self.root:
            return self.get_max(self.root)

    def get_max(self, node):
        if node.rightchild:
            return self.get_max(node.rightchild)
        return node.data

    def traverse(self):
        if self.root:
            self.traverse_in_order(self.root)

    def traverse_in_order(self, node):
        if node.leftchild:
            self.traverse_in_order(node.leftchild)

        print(node.data)

        if node.rightchild:
            self.traverse_in_order(node.rightchild)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove_node` is a recursive function. This code is designed so that whenever given data equals a node(Child)'s data, delete it and get its child/ren(Grandchild/ren) and assign them to the child field of Parent node. `tempnode` is returned to the previous recursion.

As it is done here

```
if data < node.data:
    node.leftchild = self.remove_node(data, node.leftchild)

elif data > node.data:
    node.rightchild = self.remove_node(data, node.rightchild)
```

and here

```
print('removing the node with two childs')
tempnode = self.get_predessor(node.leftchild)
node.data = tempnode.data
node.leftchild = self.remove_node(tempnode.data, node.leftchild)
```

Comment: Yep, and the answer to the first question (what `if not node: return node` means) is readability - it looks better than `if node:` and all the code from below indented for 4 more spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But i still have a point that is unclear..
is not the function ended when return "tempnode"?
How it going back to the front?

Comment: `remove_node` calls another `remove_node` which calls another `remove_node` and this goes on and on. Yes, the function ends when `return tempnode` is executed after which the caller `remove_node` continues execution. Find a tutorial on recursion and check how it is done in Python and only then you will find this code plausible.